# struct function passing and returning

Tags: c, function, struct

Can anyone help me out to code the main function of this aadjacentElementsProduct function? 
the question is:

This is what i tried :

```
struct arr_integer
{
  int size;
 int arr[];
};
int adjacentElementsProduct(struct arr_integer inputArray);
int main()
{
  int res,i;
  struct arr_integer array;
  printf("Enter size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &array.size);
  printf("Enter the elements in array: ");
  for (i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
  {
        scanf("%d", &array.arr[i]);
  }
      printf("%d\n", array.arr[2]); 
 res = adjacentElementsProduct(array);
 printf("Max is %d", res);
 getch();

 }
```

Given an array of integers, find the pair of adjacent elements that has the largest product and return that product.

Example

For `inputArray = [3, 6, -2, -5, 7, 3],` the output should be `adjacentElementsProduct(inputArray) = 21`
.

`7` and `3` produce the largest product.

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(struct arr_integer inputArray)
{
    int arrLength = inputArray.size;
    int max = inputArray.arr[0] * inputArray.arr[1];

    for (int i = 1; i < arrLength - 1; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray.arr[i] * inputArray.arr[i + 1] > max)
        {
            max = inputArray.arr[i] * inputArray.arr[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: In short: What have you tried, and how didn't your attempt work?

Comment: @Muneer Please update the post by pressing "edit", so we get the code formatting.

Comment: This code looks ok as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Lundin - the OP did post a comment and removed it.   The struct contains a flexible array member, but memory for the array is not being allocated.

Comment: Please change the question's title. You are not asking anything about passing structs to functions. Other than that, the code looks OK. You could optimize it if you were dealing with a really large array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude edited

Comment: @Lundin check the question again i edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure member `arr` is a [*flexible array member*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member). By default it doesn't have a size or even memory allocated for it, it needs to be allocated. And that can only be done through dynamic allocation of *the whole structure* (using e.g. `malloc`).

So the solution is something like

```
struct arr_integer *array;
size_t array_size;

// Get the number of elements for the array
printf("Enter size of the array: ");
scanf("%zd", &array_size);

// Allocate memory for both the structure and the array data
array = malloc(sizeof *array + sizeof *array->arr * array_size);
array->size = array_size;

// Now you can initialize `array->arr[i]` for any `i` between `0` and `array->size - 1`
```

Answer (score 1):

@Muneer. You just need to readjust your ***for loop*** as follows:

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(struct arr_integer inputArray)
{
    int arrLength = inputArray.size;
    int max = inputArray.arr[0] * inputArray.arr[1];

    for (int i = 2; i < arrLength - 1; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray.arr[i-1] * inputArray.arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = inputArray.arr[i-1] * inputArray.arr[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Notice the first value of **i** in the loop (***i=2***)

Comment: How exactly is this any better than what the OP had?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't allocate any memory. Your struct with the `[]` syntax in the end is called "flexible array member". It can only be used if you allocate memory for the struct manually, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

printf("Enter size of the array: ");
int size;
scanf("%d", &size);

struct arr_integer* array = malloc( sizeof(*array) + sizeof(int[size]) );
array->size = size;

printf("Enter the elements in array: ");
for (i = 0; i < array.size; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &array.arr[i]);
}

...
free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answers about the missing memory allocation are correct, I think it would be easier to change it thus:

```
struct arr_integer
{
  int size;
  int *arr; //<<<<<<<<<<
};

int adjacentElementsProduct(struct arr_integer inputArray);

int main()
{
  int res,i;
  struct arr_integer array;
  printf("Enter size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &array.size);
  //Of course add check for return value of scanf and to
  // the validity of the size
  array.arr = malloc(array.size * sizeof(*array.arr));
  //and check the malloc return
  //and later free the allocated memory!

.
.
.
```

This allows the OP to still use 'conventional' syntax for the declaration of the struct, and malloc - ing only the dynamic part. I think it is more readable.

Comment: why can't i use `int arr[]` instead of `int *arr` ?

Comment: An array is not a pointer. Of importance here is that the array cannot be 'reseated', meaning it cannot be set to point to a different memory location. But malloc() will return a pointer to a new adress, and you cannot assign that to the array. Therefore smth. like 'arr = malloc(....); will not even compile.

Comment: what if i want to use to `arr[]` instead of pointer ? what do i have to change in the coding as compare to that of pointer.

Comment: That has been shown in the accepted answer. In case you don't understand: In these implementations, the **whole** memory of your struct gets allocated in one go. As I said, I don't like the readability of that code, but it might offer performance benefits. That is related to how memory **access** is being implemented, looking at cache lines, etc... But I think that is very far from where you currently are in coding.